# Align long text in tab header

Tags: css, tabs

I'm trying to do a tab header, its a list of the titles, sometimes the titles are too long and has "-" in between. So to save space I add br to breakline.

1/The problem is the distance up & down between the "-" symbols is too big, is there any way I can fix that?
is this a correct way to do it by set br tag or should I set max-width for each li for the breakline?

[This is my codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OpvZwx)

```
 <div>
   <ul>
    <li>Real Estate, <br> Building House</li>
    <li>Distribution <br>–<br> Manufacturing</li>
    <li>Media <br>–<br> Broadway theater</li>
    <li>Singer <br>–<br> dancer</li>
    <li>Real Estate</li>
    <li>Construction</li>
 </ul>
```

```
  div {width: 80%; margin: 0 auto;}
  ul {
     list-style: none;
     /* display: table; */
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0;
     margin: 0;
  }
  ul li {
     position: relative;
     font-size: 1.4rem;
     /* display: table-cell; */
     color: blue;
     text-align: center;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-right: 20px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
ul li {
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    color: red;
    max-width: 120px;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    /* padding: 0 5px; */
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 14px;
}
```

[Updated codepen](http://codepen.io/kesamkiran/pen/gmeKpv)